# Blazor bind-value:event oninput

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to trigger the model validation in Blazor by using `EditForm`.

For some reason, the `oninput` event doesn't seem to be called if using the `InputText`, but it works using a simple `input` element.

Have I missed something?

Here is an HTML sample:

```
<EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit" id="authorize">
    <h1 class="mb-3">
       <span class="d-block">Authorize</span>
    </h1>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="AuthorizeUsername">Username</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></div>
            </div>
            <InputText type="text" class="form-control" id="AuthorizeUsername" placeholder="Username" @bind-value="@Model.Username" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="AuthorizePassword">Password</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-asterisk"></i></div>
            </div>
            <InputText type="password" class="form-control" id="AuthorizePassword" placeholder="Password" @bind-value="@Model.Password" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <ValidationSummary />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt mr-1"></i> Login</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5521) which has some different ways and workarounds for the `bind-value:event` format you're using. Try using `bind-value-oninput="@Model.Password"`

Comment: Studio wont accept this anymore as syntax has changed, perhaps its a bug and should be posted on github ?

Comment: It looks like it should work.. Any examples I can find look exactly the same as what you have besides the `InputText`. So yes it may be worth creating an issue for it

Comment: I came across the same problem and I found that using the `input` element instead of the `InputText` element worked for me.

Comment: Use a capital V in `@bind-Value` because `Value` is the name of a property on the C# class `InputText`

Answer (score 14):

If you need this for validation, see the answer for this:

[How to make an EditForm Input that binds using oninput rather than onchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234446/how-to-make-an-editform-input-that-binds-using-oninput-rather-than-onchange)

**Original Answer**

TLDR: Blazor Input components do not support this out of the box. You need to roll your own by extending InputBase, and your Razor markup for your new component will put the input event binding directly on the input element.

It would be nice if this came as an out-of-the-box option, but at least there is a way to do it that isn't terrible. Be aware though that this quickly gets more complicated for more complicated input types. If you want your own `InputBase<DateTime>` derived class, for example, you need to be prepared to correctly handle DateTime formatting in the binding events.

The markup for your own version of `InputText`, lets call it `MyInputTextCode` that extends `InputBase<string>` would look something exactly like this:

```html
@inherits MyInputTextCode;

<input type="text" id="@Id" class="@Class" @bind-value="CurrentValueAsString" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
```

where `MyInputTextCode` is the class name of your implementation of `InputBase<string>`

The usage would essentially be the same as `InputText`, but you would instead use the file name (witout the extension) of your .razor markup instead of `InputText`.

**UPDATE 4-30-2020**
I no longer recommend deriving from InputBase in your code-behind, instead you can simply `@inherits` an existing form component class such as InputText and override the markup in your .razor file. If this isn't clear please comment on this answer and I'll elaborate further in this update.

Comment: When doing this, I receive following exception: `System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'.` 

Comment: @WoIIe its hard to say why that might be happening from an exception alone, if you'd like to post a new question and link it here I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: @WΩLLE-ˈvɔlə I don't think `bind-Value:event="oninput"` works on an `<InputText>` control. If you check the answer linked to in this answer it's very simple to create your own input control that updates the model value with each keystroke.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link at the beginning of your answer!

Answer (score 7):

It works on a simple input because you are binding to the html attribute "value".

InputText is a C# class. The property name you need to bind to is `Value` with a capital V.

Change all `@bind-value` occurrences to `@bind-Value` and it should work.

Comment: I receive the following error at runtime when I do this: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'`

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround for this issue would be to add a handler to @oninput and set the value to the model inside this handler:

```
<EditForm Model="Input">
    <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Text" @oninput="HandleInputTextInput" />
</EditForm>

@{
    private InputModel Input { get; } = new();
    
    private void HandleInputTextInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Input.Text = e.Value as string;
    }
    
    public class InputModel
    {
        public string? Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This way you don't need to create a new component and can still use `<InputText />`.
Draw back of course is that this might bloat your code with handlers.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, I found that changing from Blazor components such as `InputTextArea` to plain HTML `textarea` tag and leveraging the binding on them can fix the problem:

```
<textarea @bind="@ViewModel.TargetProperty" @bind:event="oninput"/>
```

or for `input` tags:

```
<input type="email" @bind="@ViewModel.Email" @bind:event="oninput"/>
```

Works in .Net 5 Blazor WASM at least.

Answer (score 1):

A similar technique as Amir Mahdi said in another answer, I just wanted to point out that this is explained on the official docs also now for Aspnetcore 6.0 and 7.0.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0

See the heading '*InputText based on the input event*'.

Here is how they suggest to use it, I however see the value of also being in charge of which client side event will trigger update (usually it will be 'oninput',  but maybe you want to use another client side event?)

Just define a new reusable component like CustomInputText.razor with the following content :

```
@inherits InputText

    <input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
           class="@CssClass"
           @bind="CurrentValueAsString"
           @bind:event="@UpdateSourceTrigger" />
    
    
    @code {
        [Parameter]
        public string UpdateSourceTrigger { get; set; } = "oninput";
     }
```

To use it inside a razor view just use it like a regular InputText field, the only thing that is adjusted is that it automatically binds to the 'oninput' client side event. You can adjust which event also is bound to do an update. This can both be positive sine you see your changes on key stroke and negative in case updating the backend from the UI is slow, as every keyboard stroke will write data back to the bound property, possibly trigger additional processing too if you have bound it to an 'autosave' feature or similar.

I used the name UpdateSourceTrigger here for the property trigger event - as this reminds me a bit how we adjusted things in WPF when to write back to two way bound fields !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep `InputText` default `onchange` event but still react to `oninput` I usually do it like this: `@oninput="@(e => <bind-value variable> = e.Value.ToString())"`

For example:

```
<InputText type="text" class="form-control" id="AuthorizeUsername" placeholder="Username" @bind-value="@Model.Username" @oninput="@(e => Model.Username = e.Value.ToString())" />
```

If you wish to use the `oninput` event **instead** of the `onchange` event then here is a complete example from https://learn.microsoft.com/ for .NET 7:

ExampleModel.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class ExampleModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Name is too long.")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

Shared/CustomInputText.razor:

```
@inherits InputText

<input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" 
       class="@CssClass" 
       @bind="CurrentValueAsString" 
       @bind:event="oninput" />
```

Pages/FormExample7.razor:

```
@page "/form-example-7"
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
@inject ILogger<FormExample7> Logger

<EditForm Model="@exampleModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <CustomInputText @bind-Value="exampleModel.Name" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

<p>
    CurrentValue: @exampleModel.Name
</p>

@code {
    private ExampleModel exampleModel = new();

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("HandleValidSubmit called");

        // Process the valid form
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0#inputtext-based-on-the-input-event

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer and a workaround:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12657

Basically `@bind-Value:event="oninput"` is not supported on `<InputText>` but you can easily derive a new control from 'InputText' which does update on input.

Quoted from the original github post for reference:

Create MyInputText.razor containing:

```
@inherits Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputText
<input @attributes="@AdditionalAttributes" class="@CssClass" @bind="@CurrentValueAsString" @bind:event="oninput" />
```

Now when you use `<MyInputText @bind-Value="@someval" />` it will behave just like InputText except it updates on each keystroke.